# Why does nsupdate fail with "operation canceled"?

Tags: bind, dynamic-dns, nsupdate

I'm trying to dynamically update a DNS server using `nsupdate`, running `nsupdate -k mykey.private -d -v ./my-nsupdate-commands.txt`.

But I get the error:

```
Communication with 192.0.2.0#53 failed: operation canceled
```

**In which cases can `nsupdate` result in `operation canceled`?**

---

Full output:

```
Creating key...
Sending update to 192.0.2.0#53
Outgoing update query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: NOERROR, id:  47216
;; flags:; ZONE: 1, PREREQ: 0, UPDATE: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; ZONE SECTION:
;example.com.        IN  SOA

;; UPDATE SECTION:
mydomain.example.com.    0 ANY A 
mydomain.example.com.    61  IN  A 212.51.139.142

;; TSIG PSEUDOSECTION:
mydomain.example.com.    0 ANY TSIG  hmac-sha512. 1623020003 300 64 ... ... 47216 NOERROR 0 

; Communication with 192.0.2.0#53 failed: operation canceled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The target server's firewall may be blocking TCP port 53.**

Even though DNS usually uses UDP, `nsupdate` sometimes needs TCP; see `man nsupdate`:

> By default, nsupdate uses UDP to send update requests to the name server  unless  they  are too large to fit in a UDP request, in which case TCP is used.

Comment: « `nsupdate` sometimes needs UDP » — did you mean to say TCP here?